paypal authorization code user on my platform
i am currently working on paypal payouts. for that i had to setup seller paypal account and store paypal email to store in my db for future payouts i created this html page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'assets/common/image/favicon.svg' %}" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/common/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/utils/SFUIDisplay.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/utils/toastr.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/web/css/scss/main.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/web/css/scss/modal.css' %}">
    <title>Get Paid with Paypal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="container-fluid notifications">
            <!-- start notifications section -->
            <section class="mt-5">
                <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <h1 class="page-title mb-4 text-center">Get Paid with Paypal</h1>
                    <div class="col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <span id='signin-paypal'></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- end notifications section -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/api.js'></script>
<script>
paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {
    login.render ({
        "appid":"{{PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID|safe}}",
        "authend":"{{environment_Paypal}}",
        "scopes":"email",
        "containerid":"signin-paypal",
        "responseType":"code",
        "locale":"en-us",
        "buttonType":"CWP",
        "buttonShape":"pill",
        "buttonSize":"lg",
        "fullPage":"true",
        "returnurl":"return url"
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

this return url give me some code in get request that i use to fetch the information like email or account id
credentials = f"{settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID}:{settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET}"
            encoded_credentials = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode()).decode()
            print(f"Encoded Credentials: {encoded_credentials}")
            # Define the URL for getting user info
            url = f"{settings.PAYPAL_BASE_URL}/v1/oauth2/token"
            payload = f'grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}'
            headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': f"Basic {encoded_credentials}"
            }
            response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                access_token = response.json().get("access_token")
                headers = {}
                headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
                headers["Authorization"] = F"Bearer {access_token}"
                user_info_url = f"{settings.PAYPAL_BASE_URL}/v1/identity/oauth2/userinfo?schema=paypalv1.1"
                user_response = requests.get(user_info_url, headers=headers)
                
                if user_response.status_code == 200:
                    user_info = user_response.json()
                    print("User Info:", user_info)
                    payer_id = user_info.get("payer_id", None)
                    email = None
                    if "emails" in user_info:
                        for email_info in user_info["emails"]:
                            if email_info.get("primary", False) and email_info.get("confirmed", False):
                                email = email_info["value"]
                                break
                    success = True
                    response = email
                    return success , response
                else:
                    print("Failed to retrieve user info:", user_response.status_code, user_response.text)
                    response = user_response.text
                    return success , response
            else:
                print("Failed to retrieve access token:", response.status_code, response.text)
                response = response.text
                return success , response

and i got this error
"{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"unsupported grant_type"}"
note: i got this error when i use authorization_code it work fine when i used client credential that doesn;t return the result from code
how can i get the information of user using that code

for comparison, have you tried using the authorization_code with the command line curl samples from the documentation?

i have to do this with postman collection that they provide but still same error occured.

what permissions does the app have in https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications

it has the permission for payment and payouts

enable Log in with Paypal

yes it have that
